# How to calculate and get the list of months between two year in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, datetime

Trying to get the list of all months in the given range of years.

[image]

```
  var startYear = DateTime(1999);
  var endYear = DateTime(2021);
```

The result should be like

```
List monthsInRange = [
Jan 1999,
Feb 1999,
Mar 1999,
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Dec 2021
]
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

First add intl dep to your pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.16.1
```

import the package :

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

then create a function for :

```
List<String> listmonthyear(startYear, endYear) {
  List<String> listdate = []; //if you want String
  while (startYear != endYear) {
    listdate.add(DateFormat.yMMM().format(startYear).toString());
    startYear =
        new DateTime(startYear.year, startYear.month + 1, startYear.day);
  }
  return listdate;
}
```

Comment: This will fail if startYear.day is 30 or 31, and the next month is shorter.  You'll end up skipping the next month, and roll over to the beginning of the following month. Two tips: (1) use .utc always.  (2) use month + 1 only when day = 1.